# Making f active in math mode

Tags: mathcode

I am trying to correct a spacing issue in mathspec. I wish to add an extra space after the letter f in math mode, but only if it is not followed by a subscript. I don't want to do this manually every time, so I have tried this code:

```
\makeatletter
\mathcode`f="8000
\DeclareMathSymbol{\f}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`f}
\newcommand{\mathf}{\@ifnextchar_{\f}{\f \,}}
\begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`\f
    \lowercase{\gdef~{\ifnum\the\mathgroup=\m@ne \mathf \else \f \fi}}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

But it doesn't work. It adds the space regardless! How could I fix this?

Comment: the token after `\mathf` is always `\else` so never _` (you are missing some `\expandafter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `\ifnum` is evaluated, `\else` is not removed, so `\mathf` sees it and it never scans further for a next `_`. You should have `\expandafter\mathf` instead, so the `\else` is removed up to the matching `\fi` before `\mathf` is expanded.

However, I suggest you some better code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin)[Numbers=Lining]{Hoefler Text}
\setmathrm[Numbers=Lining]{Hoefler Text}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \edef\SAVEfCODE{\the\Umathcodenum`f } % just for the test
  \Umathcharnumdef\math@f\Umathcodenum`f 
  \mathcode`f=\string"8000 }
\begingroup\lccode`~=`f
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~{%
    \math@f
    \ifnum\mathgroup=\m@ne
      \expandafter\@firstofone
    \else
      \expandafter\@gobble
    \fi
    {\@ifnextchar_{\relax}{\,}}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f(x)f_1(x)\mathbf{f}(x)\mathbf{f}_1(x)\mathbf{f_1}(x)$

%% Just to show the difference
\Umathcodenum`f=\SAVEfCODE\relax
$f(x)f_1(x)\mathbf{f}(x)\mathbf{f}_1(x)\mathbf{f_1}(x)$

\end{document}
```

The parts with `\SAVEfcode` are just for showing the difference.

[image]

Note: in `\ifnum\the\mathgroup`, `\the` is redundant, because `\mathgroup` *is* a number. I used `\Umath...` because its safer in the context of `mathspec`.

Comment: Then how to add space to the both side of f?

Comment: @Mogic Add `\,` or `\mkern2mu` (experiment with the value) before `\math@f`