# Kerning for subscripts of \sigma?

Tags: xetex, microtype, kerning

Is there any way to reduce the distance inside σ₀ and between `\sigma` and its subscript in general in the following setup automatically? That is, each time you type in `\sigma_0` (or `\sigma_1` etc.), you wish the actual output to be more consistent with `\sigma_{\!0}` (or `\sigma_{\!1}` etc.).

Input:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american,british,french,norsk,german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{mathic=true} %%% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3496/
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,range={\setminus}]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,Extension=.otf,range={"2A3E},BoldFont=XITSMath-Bold]{XITSMath-Regular}%%% The fat semicolon
\usepackage[babel=true,verbose=errors]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\[\sigma_0 \sigma_0\]
\[\sigma_{\!0} \sigma_{\!0}\]
\end{document}
```

Output so far:

[image]

As you see, in the upper line the left zero seems to be more close to the right σ (which doesn't make any sense) than to the left one (which would make sense). The kerning in the lower line makes more sense.

I guess, this would be easier than [Subscript kerning for specific letters in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301119/subscript-kerning-for-specific-letters-in-xelatex), since we already have `\sigma` as a macro and can redefine it.

For which letters in the subscript position the kerning should be improved (and how) is intentionally left unspecified; improving the kerning in `\sigma_<any single arabic digit or any single Latin small letter>` or `\sigma_{<any nonempty sequence of arabic digits and Latin small letters>`} would suffice as a start. Of course, for σ_{\mathrm{T}} we might need less kerning (e.g., only -1mu rather than -3mu), and that's why capital Latin letters would need more work (and are not asked for in the first step). As of now, I intend to use the following subscripts: all the digits, *i*, *j*, *k*, k (yes, this one upright), *n*, *i* + 1, *i* - 1.

Comment: Do you want to change the behaviour for `\sigma_<any single number>`, or for `\sigma_<any single character>`, or `\sigma_<anything>`, or somthing else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I defined a command `\AddtoKernList{<token list>}{<mu kern>}` which will add the first token of the `<token list>` to a lookup table (the assignment is local). Later on, the `\sigma` command is redefined to to check for a subscript; if the subscript is found, then it looks the first token in the subscript in the lookup list. If that token is found, `\mkern<mu kern>` is applied right before the subscript.

I search for the subscript using `\peek_catcode_remove:NTF`. I could've significantly reduced the code if I had used `xparse`'s `e`-type arguments, as Henri Menke suggested (thanks :-) and egreg did. I'll keep my answer with the first approach, however.

With the defined commands, the input:

```
$\sigma_{abc} \sigma^a_0 \sigma_0^b \sigma^c_T$

\AddtoKernList{0}{-\thinmuskip}

$\sigma_{abc} \sigma_0^a \sigma^b_0 \sigma^c_T$

\AddtoKernList{T}{-1mu}

$\sigma_{abc} \sigma_0^a \sigma^b_0 \sigma^c_T$
```

produces (with LuaTeX and `lua-visual-debug` to show the negative kern):

> [image]

Notice that the order of subscript and superscript does not matter (anymore, thanks to *far too many* lines of code) and notice also that the character is kerned only after the `\AddtoKernList` instruction. To add temporarily a token to this list, do the assignment in a group.

Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage{unravel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american,british,french,norsk,german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{mathic=true} %%% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3496/
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,range={\setminus}]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,Extension=.otf,range={"2A3E},BoldFont=XITSMath-Bold]{XITSMath-Regular}%%% The fat semicolon
\usepackage[babel=true,verbose=errors]{microtype}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__userxlixk_kern_case_tl
\AtBeginDocument{
  \cs_new_eq:NN \__userxlixk_actual_sigma: \sigma
  \RenewDocumentCommand\sigma{}
    { \__userxlixk_sigma: }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\AddtoKernList{mm}
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__userxlixk_kern_case_tl
      { { #1 }{ \tex_mskip:D #2 \scan_stop: #1 } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__userxlixk_sigma:
  {
    \peek_catcode_remove:NTF \c_math_subscript_token
      { \__userxlixk_sigma_check_group:n }
      { \__userxlixk_sigma_check_superscript: }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__userxlixk_sigma_check_group:n #1
  {
    \exp_args:NNf
    \__userxlixk_actual_sigma: \c_math_subscript_token
      { \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:n {#1} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__userxlixk_sigma_check_superscript:
  {
    \peek_catcode_remove:NTF \c_math_superscript_token
      { \__userxlixk_sigma_check_sub_after_sup:n }
      { \__userxlixk_actual_sigma: }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__userxlixk_sigma_check_sub_after_sup:n #1
  {
    \peek_catcode_remove:NTF \c_math_subscript_token
      { \__userxlixk_sigma_sub_after_sup:nn {#1} }
      { \__userxlixk_actual_sigma: \c_math_superscript_token {#1} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__userxlixk_sigma_sub_after_sup:nn #1 #2
  {
    \exp_args:NNf
    \__userxlixk_actual_sigma: \c_math_subscript_token
      { \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:n {#2} }
    \c_math_superscript_token {#1}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:n #1
  { \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:Nw #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:Nw #1 #2 \q_stop
  {
    \exp_args:NNo
    \tl_case:NnF #1
      { \l__userxlixk_kern_case_tl }
      {#1}
    #2
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\sigma_{abc} \sigma^a_0 \sigma_0^b \sigma^c_T$

\AddtoKernList{0}{-\thinmuskip}

$\sigma_{abc} \sigma_0^a \sigma^b_0 \sigma^c_T$

\AddtoKernList{T}{-1mu}

$\sigma_{abc} \sigma_0^a \sigma^b_0 \sigma^c_T$

\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer the `e`-type argument you can add my lookup list to egreg's answer:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\standardsigma\sigma
  \let\sigma\kernedsigma
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__userxlixk_kern_case_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\AddtoKernList{mm}
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__userxlixk_kern_case_tl
      { { #1 }{ \tex_mskip:D #2 \scan_stop: #1 } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:n #1
  { \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:Nw #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:Nw #1 #2 \q_stop
  {
    \exp_args:NNo
    \tl_case:NnF #1
      { \l__userxlixk_kern_case_tl }
      {#1}
    #2
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \CheckKernListUse \__userxlixk_check_kern_list_use:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\kernedsigma}{e{_^}}{%
  \csname exp_args:NNf\endcsname
  \standardsigma_
    {\IfValueT{#1}{\CheckKernListUse{#1}}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}%
}
```

Comment: To make it work for both `\sigma_a^b` and `\sigma^b_a` you could use an `e`-type argument (“embellishments”).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for the idea :-) I completely forgot about those. I didn't know, however, that the order in which the arguments were used didn't matter.

Comment: @user49915 If I understand correctly, you want to have a list of characters and the amount of kern to apply to each, is that it?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik In any case you should have used an `e`-type argument rather than checking the catcode manually.

Comment: @user49915 See the edit :-)

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, after your comment I noticed that. I have the bad habit of over-complicating things. I'll leave the `e`-type in egreg's answer. Anyhow thanks for the advice :-)

Comment: @user49915 Not easily, sorry. The lookup table thingy relies on `expl3`'s `\tl_case:NnF` whose first argument is an `N` type (if you don't know `expl3`, an `N` type is a single token argument). For a token list I'd need a `\tl_case:nnF` (with a lowercase `n`), which doesn't exist in `expl3`. I know how to build this `\tl_case:nnF`, but unfortunately I don't have the time right now, and it will be a _very_ slow code. I suggest you to do `\def\mathrmk{\mathrm{k}}` and then use this `\mathrmk` for the time being. Once I have the time I'll make it for you.

Comment: @user49915 Oops, my bad, I forgot it there. Yes, certainly remove it!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the `e` argument type of `xparse`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american,british,french,norsk,german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[babel=true,verbose=errors]{microtype}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[
  range={\setminus},
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}[
  Extension=.otf,
  range={"2A3E},
  BoldFont=XITSMath-Bold,
]

%\mathtoolsset{mathic=true} %%% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3496/

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\standardsigma\sigma
  \let\sigma\kernedsigma
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\kernedsigma}{e{_^}}{%
  \standardsigma
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\!#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[\sigma_0 \sigma_0^2 \sigma^2_0\]
\[\standardsigma_{\!0} \standardsigma_{\!0}^2 \standardsigma^2_{\!0}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user49915 I'm not sure what could be the difference. One can quite easily *exclude* some symbols from being kerned.

Comment: @user49915 I don't know what subscripts you want to use next to `\sigma`. You probably should kern *less* than -3mu generally.