# How to change "'" and "\prime" into the symbols in the setting font and how to add spacing to the both side of italic "f" in math mode only?

Tags: spacing, symbols, mathspec

First, a minimal working example is as following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts(Digits,Latin){Times}%a replacement of the font that I am using now
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

$a'+b=c^\prime$ and $(f),[f],\{f\}$.

\end{document}
```

And its output by `xelatex` is

[image]

So my questions are:

> 1. The primes in the picture produced by the codes `'` and `\prime` are both from the default `Computer Modern` font. Then how to change `'` and `\prime` into the symbols in the setting `Times` font? Hope a global setting but not a local one.
> 2. The space at the both side of the italic `f` in math mode is so small that the parenthesis and `f` are too close. Then how to add spacing to the both side of the italic `f` in math mode only (but not in text mode)? Hope a global setting but not a local one too.

**Question 2 has been solved as following, then for question 1 who can help me?**

Comment: using mathspec and times you are using a text font for math so will always get suboptimal spacing, could you consider unicode-math package and Stix Two Math font which is a times-like font designed for math

Comment: @David Carlisle Actually NO since the font that I am using in fact can only be used in such a way. Also I tried other ways but failed, for example, reediting the font file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `"f` (and similarly for other letters) as mentioned in the manual of `mathspec`.

Note that `'` is the same as `^{\prime}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts(Digits,Latin){Times}%a replacement of the font that I am using now
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

$a'+b="f^\prime$ and $("f),["f],\{"f\}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For question 2, I prefer a global answer to the local one. For question 1,` '` and `^\prime` are indeed the same. But what I need is to make them become the symbol in the `Times` font instead of the default `Computer Modern` font. So question 1 is still note solved.

Comment: To thanks for your sincere help for question 2, I pick your answer although there is no well answer to question 1 now.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, I get an answer which coms from [the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210215/making-f-active-in-math-mode/210228?noredirect=1#comment1412941_210228) with the help of @egreg. I post the answer here:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \Umathcharnumdef\math@f\Umathcodenum`f 
    \mathcode`f=\string"8000}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`f
\lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{%
        \mkern3mu\math@f
        \ifnum\mathgroup=\m@ne
        \expandafter\@firstofone
        \else
        \expandafter\@gobble
        \fi
        {\@ifnextchar_{\relax}{\mkern3mu}}%
    }
}
\makeatother
```

And the following is the output for the revision:

[image]